# save in a text file list of files with the size of each file

Tags: bash, command-line

I am trying to save the list of all files including size in a text file.

Using the command `find *> yourfilename.csv` I can export only the names of the files.

how can I also add the file size?

Comment: `du -a > yourfilename.csv`?

Comment: Do you mean all files on your system or all files in a particular directory?

Comment: Do you want their size (as reported by ls -l) or disk usage (as reported by du or ls -s)?  See also [How can I get the size of a file in a bash script?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/321502)

Comment: with du -a > yourfilename.csv  I did it !

Comment: @artemisVA Note that that command would likely give you the physical size of files and directories. This is not what you asked about in the question (you only mentioned "files"). It is also unclear whether you want the physical or the logical/apparent size of files. The two are different for _sparse_ files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `bash` shell on Linux (or on a system with a compatible `stat` implementation):

```bash
shopt -s globstar dotglob nullglob

for pathname in ./**/*; do
    if [[ -f $pathname ]] && [[ ! -h $pathname ]]; then
        stat -c $'%s\t%n' "$pathname"
    fi
done >outfile.csv
```

For `bash` on OpenBSD (or on some other BSD systems with a similar implementation of `stat`), use

```bash
shopt -s globstar dotglob nullglob

for pathname in ./**/*; do
    if [[ -f $pathname ]] && [[ ! -h $pathname ]]; then
        stat -f '%z%t%N' "$pathname"
    fi
done >outfile.csv
```

Both of these would iterate over all names in or below the current directory.  For each regular file, `stat` is called and the apparent file size in bytes and the files pathname is printed with a tab-character in-between.

---

Using only the `zsh` shell:

```
zmodload -F zsh/stat b:zstat
zstat -n +size ./**/*(D.)
```

This makes the built-in `zstat` command available in the shell and then uses that to get the pathname and apparent file size in bytes of each regular file in or below the current directory (including files with hidden names).

The output might look something like this for a shallow directory with only a few small files:

```
./file1 136
./file2 136
./somedir/file3 136
```

... so not very CSV-like.

This could also be done in a simple loop, which would allow us to format it a bit more precisely:

```sh
zstat -L -A data -n +size ./**/*(D.)
for name size in $data; do
    printf '%s\t%s\n' $size $name
done >outfile.csv
```

This would call `zstat` for all the regular files in or below the current directory, store the result in the array `data`, and then loop over the entries of that array (will be alternating pathnames and file sizes).  For each pathname/size pair, print the size in bytes first, followed by a tab and the pathname. Here, the output is put into `outfile.csv` in the current directory.

A shortened version that gets rid of the loop but pays for it in somewhat more obscure code (unless you're familiar with `printf` format strings):

```sh
zstat -L -A data -n +size ./**/*(D.)
printf '%2$s\t%1$s\n' $data >outfile.csv
```

The `printf` format `%2$s\t%1$s\n` specifies that two arguments should outputted as strings, but in reverse order (the `data` array stores pairs of pathnames and file sizes, in that order), with a tab in-between them.  The format will be reused for each pair of pathnames and file size until the `data` array is exhausted.

---

None of the above variations takes care to CSV-quote pathnames that contain tabs or newlines.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you'd like it comma delimited for your CSV file, and that none of the file names contain double quote, comma or newline characters, with the GNU implementation of `find`, try:

```
find -printf "%p,%s\n" >filename.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-ls` option for find:

```
find /dir -ls >filename.csv
```

However this will print more information than just the filename and size.

Alternatively you could use `find` in combination with `stat`:

```
find /dir -exec printf '%s,' {} \; -exec stat -f %z {} \; >filename.csv
```

This will print the filename and the size in bytes separated by a comma (since you are outputting to a csv file, you could also replace this with your preferred delimiter.)

Comment: `-printf '%s\t%p\n'`

Comment: @Kusalananda: Not every version of find has `-printf`

Comment: If you're using `stat` like that, you're already assuming a Linux system.

Comment: Or macos.......=)

Comment: Touché. So it is.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `ls`:

1. `ls -l > output` - This will save a listing of the directory (including size) inside the file `output`, like so:

```
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ashleyprimo ashleyprimo 124 Jan  4 20:01 test1
-rw-r--r-- 1 ashleyprimo ashleyprimo   0 Jan  4 19:56 test2
-rw-r--r-- 1 ashleyprimo ashleyprimo   0 Jan  4 19:56 test3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ashleyprimo ashleyprimo   0 Jan  4 19:56 test5
```

You can add `-a` to include hidden files (e.g. those with a . in front of them); and you can add a `-h` to make the size output "human readable" - (e.g. displayed in MB, GB, etc instead of bytes as shown above)

If you literally want a simple size output of the current directories files, then you can use: `ls -lh | grep -vE "total|\." | awk {'print $5 " " $9'} > output` which will output like so:

```
124 test1
0 test2
0 test3
0 test5
```