# MAC OSX / Bash Problem - Sorting strings as a date

Tags: date, sort, macos

I have file output in a CSV file I want to sort by date time but the date time appears as below, with the time and year appearing in a different order.

Using this command to produce the file listing:

```
find /Volumes/myVolume  -type f -exec  ls -1 -aldT {} \; |cut -c35-300 |sort  -r -k5,5 -s |sort -k3,3 -s

1579099156  6 Apr 09:33:03 2023 /Volumes/myvolume/myfile
```

My `sort` commands work but as the second sort field is a Month, it sorts it in Alpha order whereas I'd rather it saw it as a month and sorted it in month order. (e.g. Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.).

Is there a way to this without changing how the file listing is produced ?

I can modify the file listing if necessary, which aids me in generating a recursive listing of file outputs that I can subsequently parse for other tasks.

I am able to adjust the field order, but I require all fields to be displayed, with the filename consistently appearing as the last one.

Answer (score 4):

On OSX, you should have access to `zsh` which will allow you to make use of its glob qualifiers to sort matching filenames by modification time

```
/Volumes/myVolume/**/*(.DOm)
```

You can then utilize its `zstat` module in a similar way to that described in [save in a text file list of files with the size of each file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560360/65304) to get and print the size and mtime. So either (adapting that method directly)

```
zmodload -F zsh/stat b:zstat

zstat -F '%d %b %T %Y' -A data -n /Volumes/myVolume/**/*(.DOm)
for name _ _ _ _ _ _ _ size _ mtime _ _ _ in $data; do 
  printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' $size $mtime $name
done
```

or with an explicit loop (perhaps more readable)

```
zmodload -F zsh/stat b:zstat

for f in  /Volumes/myVolume/**/*(.NDOm); do
  zstat -LF '%d %b %T %Y' -H s -- $f &&
    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' $s[size] $s[mtime] $f
done
```

Answer (score 3):

`ls` itself has the capability to sort files based on date:

```
  ls -l[r]t
```

Hence, you could work "backwards": instead of using `ls` first and sort afterwards prepare the list of files first and let `ls` do the sorting:

```
  ls -lrt $(find /start/dir -type f -print)
```

Change the options to `ls` according to your needs, but be shure to include "t" for sorting by time (and maybe "r" for a reverse sort order).

Answer (score 1):

Dates are awful things that vary in structure.  Are you okay with using Epoch time?  That's a simple number that can be sorted with ease.  Also, this would make your command more portable.

Try substituting this into your find exec parameters.

```
ls -1 -D "+%s" -alT
```

Example:

```
user@host ~ % ls -1 -D "+%s" -alT minicom.log
-rw-r--r--  1 user  group  35 +1683075462 minicom.log
user@hose ~ % ls -1alT minicom.log
-rw-r--r--  1 user  group  35  3 May 12:57:42 2023 minicom.log
```

And if we take the epoch time of `1683075462` and convert it with `date`

```
user@host ~ % date -r 1683075462
Wed  3 May 2023 12:57:42 NZST
```

Background, epoch/epoc time is also called unix time, and represents "the number of seconds since 00:00 on 1 January 1970"